# How can I split this dataframe in columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, split

I have a Pandas dataframe with N columns, each column containing a list of 3 values (`x`, `y` and `z`):

[image: A small slice of the dataframe]

I want to get a new dataframe containing 3N columns, each one containing each of the coordinate values for each column (for example, `IndexDistalJoint_x`, `IndexDistalJoint_y` and `IndexDistalJoint_z`, and so on with the remaining original columns).

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this DataFrame:

```py
              A             B             C
0     [1, 2, 3]     [4, 5, 6]     [7, 8, 9]
1  [10, 11, 12]  [13, 14, 15]  [16, 17, 18]
```

Then:

```py
data = []
for c in df.columns:
    x = df[c].apply(pd.Series)
    x.columns = [f"{c}_{ch}" for ch in "xyz"]
    data.append(x)

print(pd.concat(data, axis=1))
```

Prints:

```
   A_x  A_y  A_z  B_x  B_y  B_z  C_x  C_y  C_z
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
1   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Andrej. Finally, I managed to do it more or less the same way.